# How to fix drush issue "Could not bootstrap at phase 5"?

Tags: 8, drush

I installed drush via Composer. I am using drush 9.5.2 with Drupal 8.6.4.

I mention that everything is fine on local. However, in a docker instance in GitLab CI, when I execute `vendor/bin/drush updatedb -y -vvv`, I get:

```
 [preflight] Config paths: /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml,/builds/v2/my-project/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /builds/v2/my-project/web/drush/sites,/builds/v2/my-project/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/src,/builds/v2/my-project/drush
 [bootstrap] Starting bootstrap to full [0.09 sec, 8.27 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase 5 [0.09 sec, 8.27 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.09 sec, 8.27 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.09 sec, 8.27 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.09 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.09 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Change working directory to /builds/v2/my-project/web [0.09 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal 8.6.4 root directory at /builds/v2/my-project/web [0.1 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.1 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.1 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.11 sec, 9.14 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.11 sec, 9.14 MB]
 [info] sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.11 sec, 9.28 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_FfJCYU --database=my_project --host=xxx.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --silent -A < /tmp/drush_BsP1AL > /dev/null [0.11 sec, 9.28 MB]
 [info] sql-query: SELECT 1 FROM key_value LIMIT 1; [0.23 sec, 9.28 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_TOHYme --database=my_project --host=xxx.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --silent -A < /tmp/drush_4SNKF4 > /dev/null [0.23 sec, 9.28 MB]
 [notice] Missing database table: key_value [0.35 sec, 9.28 MB]
 [bootstrap] Could not bootstrap at phase 5 [0.35 sec, 9.28 MB]

In BootstrapHook.php line 32:

  [Exception]                                                         
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.  


Exception trace:
 () at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:32
 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:117
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:391
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:221
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:971
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:248
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:112
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:41
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:66
 require() at /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

updatedb [--cache-clear [CACHE-CLEAR]] [--entity-updates] [--post-updates [POST-UPDATES]] [--no-cache-clear] [--no-post-updates] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--druplicon] [--] <command>
```

I mention that **the command mysql -V is working.**

And when I execute `vendor/bin/drush sql:connect -vvv`, I get:

```
 [preflight] Config paths: /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml,/builds/v2/my-project/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /builds/v2/my-project/web/drush/sites,/builds/v2/my-project/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /builds/v2/my-project/vendor/drush/drush/src,/builds/v2/my-project/drush
 [bootstrap] Starting bootstrap to max [0.1 sec, 8.27 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.1 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Change working directory to /builds/v2/my-project/web [0.1 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal 8.6.4 root directory at /builds/v2/my-project/web [0.1 sec, 8.4 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.11 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.11 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.11 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.11 sec, 9.11 MB]
mysql --user=my_project --password=xxx --database=my_project --host=xxx.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 -A
```

So, no problem with `drush sql:connect`.

**Does the notice *"Missing database table: key_value"* could cause the issue?**
How could we troubleshoot the issue?

Just in case, here is the build part of my *gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
build:
  stage: build

  before_script:
    - apt-get update

    #install additional gd extension, that is required by Drupal
    - apt-get install libpng-dev -y
    - docker-php-ext-install gd

    #install mysql-cli
    - apt-get install -y mysql-client

    #install composer
    - apt-get install zip unzip
    - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
    - php composer-setup.php
    - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

    #install composer package to run parallel tasks
    - composer -n global require -n "hirak/prestissimo"

  script:
    - mysql -V
    - php composer.phar install
    - vendor/bin/drush
    - vendor/bin/drush sql:connect -vvv
    - vendor/bin/drush updatedb -y -vvv
    - vendor/bin/drush config-import -y
    - vendor/bin/drush cache-rebuild -y
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I had to export my local database and import it in the production server database (same for the sync configuration files).